# jQuery ajax enviando vía GET configurando envío por POST

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario por **ajax** mediante **POST** desde un sitio (todo local) a otro, pero estoy viendo desde la consola de los navegadores y desde el archivo access_log que el envío del formulario lo esta haciendo vía **GET**.

En el access_log de sitiolocal1.co obtengo lo siguiente:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2016:13:09:44 -0500] "GET /user/register?callback=jQuery112405891064639177535_1479319237541&id=&first_name=N%C3%A9stor&last_name=Acevedo&email=mi_email%40gmail.com&password=222222&password1=222222 HTTP/1.1" 405 4390 "http://localhost/wordpress/2016/11/11/hola-mundo/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"**
```

¿Por qué a pesar de configurar **ajax** para el envío por POST está haciéndolo por GET?

```
$("#form-register").submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    var data = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "localdomain.co/user/register",
        data: data, 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        type: 'POST', 
        success: function (result) { 
            alert(result.status); 
        } 
    }});
})
```

Comment: El código es:
        $("#form-register").submit(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localdomain.co/user/register",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                        alert(result.status);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

Comment: acabo de editar tu pregunta, verifica si ese punto y coma en la URL te da problemas.

Comment: Gracias, bueno, el punto y coma se me fue de más aunque no está en el código original.

Comment: puedes poner el codigo html de tu formulario?

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir, de paso, te parece si agregas un pantallazo de la parte de Network de tu navegador (F12 para las Dev Tools) ahí debe salir qué tipo de request estás enviando al server :D

Comment: Imagen de [Google Chrome](https://postimg.org/image/nhna0z0i5/)

Imagen de [Firefox](https://postimg.org/image/9chgz5rgt/)

Ambas imágenes muestran que el método es GET así en el ajax le indique que es POST.

Comment: @sioesi como se trata de jQuery con Ajax no importan los campos del formulario sino el por qué está enviando por GET. Sin embargo luego en una respuesta a esta publicación pongo el html.

Comment: Me imaginaba que en el <form> tuvieras action y method. Aunque vi que haces un preventDefault asi que descarto esa opcion. Por otro lado como dices tu como es ajax quizas podrias ahorrarte el formulario y hacer un .click de un boton normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, leyendo muchísimos foros, preguntas similares a esta y algunas documentaciones he visto que **JSONP** sólo hace peticiones tipo *GET* sin importar cómo se configure $.ajax.

Esta documentación no se encuentra en el sitio web de jQuery así que lo dejo como anotación y anécdota para muchos.

Comment: me parece perfecto que busques, encuentres y aprendas, sigue investigando! gracias por colaborar con el crecimiento de esta comunidad. Aqui un par de enlaces para complementar la respuesta: https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/ y http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23438/security-risks-with-jsonp

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de probar tu código, tenés una llave de más al cerrar la llamada a la función Ajax:
`}});`

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/21081)

Comment: Perdón, mi respuesta es correcta, probaste lo que yo dije antes de asegurar que no lo es?

Comment: No es una respuesta porque no es lo que está preguntando el usuario. Si no se queja de que el código no compila puede suceder que la errata se haya introducido al adaptar el código en la pregunta. Esta respuesta debería ser un comentario.